# PowerShell to delete emails from Mailbox

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server

I'm using this command as I want to delete email from example@email.com which older than 7 days, and this is the command I use:`New-InboxRule -Mailbox "user@email.com" -Name "DeleteOldEmails" -From "example@email.com" -ReceivedBeforeDate ((Get-Date).AddDays(1-$DaysOld).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) -MoveToFolder "Deleted Items"` but it says can not find a mailbox called "Delete Items". But when I use Get-MailboxFolder -GetChildren I found "Delete Items" is a childfolder. Is that why this script can not find the folder? How to get this script running?

This is the script I've been trying:

```
New-InboxRule -Mailbox "user@email.com" -Name "DeleteOldEmails" -From "example@email.com" -ReceivedBeforeDate ((Get-Date).AddDays(1-$DaysOld).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) -MoveToFolder "Deleted Items"
```